# "Undefined variable: Environment" when editing SConscript file in Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, scons

I have an `SCons` project (an implementation of the Generic Mapping Tools tutorial at http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/doc/latest/GMT_Tutorial.html using `SCons` rather than shell scripts), and I am using Eclipse Neon to edit the `Sconstruct` file.

The `Sconstruct` file starts in quite a standard way (the rest of the file is immaterial to this question).

```
import os
import collections

env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)

bld = Builder(action = 'ps2pdf $SOURCE $TARGET', \
              suffix = '.pdf', \
              src_suffix = '.ps')
```

What is annoying me is that while the build works perfectly using `scons`, Eclipse keeps marking the `Environment` and `Builder` constructions as "Undefined variables".

I installed the `SConsolidator` plugin, but it makes no difference.

I find the marking of an error that is not an error incredibly annoying.

While I could do something like tell Eclipse to ignore the error, I would prefer something more intelligent, such as adding `Scons` to the library path. I have tried adding `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.5.1\Scons` and `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.5.1\Scons\Scripts` to the Python Interpreter Paths (Window → Preferences → PyDev → Interpreters → Python Interpreters → Paths), and using an import directive like `from SConscript.SCons import *` but it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try library path:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.5.1\
```

Then

```
from SCons.Script import *
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first - if you know exactly where does your plugin keep it's symbol index(es) make sure that they don't get deleted by whatever the editor/IDE/build think they are doing to "be helpful".

Python plugins for editors easily get confused and you may need you to draw very explicit and detailed picture and train them a bit (by stopping the code in debugger) in order for a scanner/indexer to "wake up" and finally scan and index all symbols.

What I do in VS (with PTVS) is to make one proj for Scons_lib (home at C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.5.0), another for Scons_Scripts (C:\Python27\Scripts\, startup file: scons.py)

and then separate projects for separate scons driven folders/builds. To get editor to immediately recognize building files as Python I add extension .scons (google's convention used in Chrome build, Sconcsript's are ProjName.scons), tell VS that .scons is also Python, rename Sconstruct to Make.scons.

Then I run in debugger, (with -f Make.scons -n of course) as many times as I can :-) trying to place breakpoints in different files form different sub-packages that I know will run. Letting scons throw exceptions for nothing (like missing Sconstuct file) is also file - the goal is to force indexer to go places because it sees that debugger is going there.

After N runs, (and/or K days). PTVS (you can consider it a plugin) all of the sudden starts recognizing all symbols, packages, sub-packages, only can't penetrate things explicitly hidden behind caches.

Gave up trying to determine which events exactly make the scanner/indexer see the light. Probably something like seeing the number of files at "unexpected" paths being in debugger. Most symbols are visible in debugger immediately, except for the files that load first (scons.py and my own file that I exec from scons.py to inject whatever I want before anything else runs.)

Also I keep PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 to make sure that it always has to load actual .py-s

It might potentially help to have a single file that would exercise something form every sub-package, litter it with breakpoints and let it be run a few times.